# How to mask green pixels?

Tags: image-processing, opencv, computer-vision, emgucv

I need to mask a green pixels in the image. 
I have have example of the masking red pixels.
Here the example:

```
Image<Hsv, Byte> hsv = image.Convert<Hsv, Byte>()

Image<Gray, Byte>[] channels = hsv.Split();

               //channels[0] is the mask for hue less than 20 or larger than 160

CvInvoke.cvInRangeS(channels[0], new MCvScalar(20), new MCvScalar(160), channels[0]);
               channels[0]._Not();
```

but, I cant understand from where those parameters where token:

```
new MCvScalar(20), new MCvScalar(160)
```

Any idea which parameters I have to take to mask the green pixels?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code masks pixels with Hue outside the range 20 - 160 (or rather masks pixeles inside the range and then inverts the mask).

First, understand HSV (Hue, Saturation, Value): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV

The actual Hue is in degrees and goes from 0 to 360 like:

[image: Hue angles]

Then see [OpenCV documentation on 8-bit HSV format](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#cvtcolor):

Hue is first calculated in 0 - 360, then divided by 2 to fit into 8-bit integer.

This means that in the original example the masked pixels have actual Hue under 40 or above 320 degrees. Apparently that's 0 degrees plus / minus 40.

For a similar range of greens you'd want 120 +/- 40, i.e. from 80 to 160. Finally converting that to 8-bit representation - from 40 to 80.

The actual code will differ from your sample though: for red they had to mask 20,160 then invert the mask. For green just masking from 40 to 80 is enough (i.e. you'll have to omit the `channels[0]._Not();` part).

Comment: actually, your original (red) solution will mask perceptually white/grey/black pixels which happen to be only slightly reddish. For better results you could mask on saturation and maybe even on value and then combine the masks with `and` or `*`. But the actual ranges depend on the problem you're trying to solve (as "green pixels" is a vague formulation)